# Iterating through two lists

Tags: loops, comma-separated-list

I have two comma delimited lists:

```
ListA(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

and

```
ListB(name1,name2,name3,name4,name5)
```

I would like to iterate through both lists at the same time, something like:

```
loop
   readvalue from list A
   readvalue from list B
   create new variable aname1{}
repeat
```

Iteration should stop, if it reaches to the end of either lists.

Comment: Did you intend to have two lists with different lengths? I.e., do you want 35 total pairs `aname1`, `aname2`,...,`aname5`,...,`gname1`,...,`gname5` ?

Comment: @will lists should be of the same length, but I want to capture any potential errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution which goes through all elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psforeach{\A}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}{%
  \psforeach{\B}{name1,name2,name3,name4,name5}{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\A\B\endcsname{Def: \A,\B}}}

\begin{document}
\csname aname1\endcsname

\csname ename4\endcsname
\end{document}
```

Make sure comma isn't active, otherwise this won't work. For example, the following fails. Also, make sure there are no spurious spaces in your lists.

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\,=13
\def\x{\endgroup
  \psforeach{\A}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}{%
    \psforeach{\B}{name1,name2,name3,name4,name5}{%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname\A\B\endcsname{Def: \A,\B}%
    }%
  }%
}
\x
```

Comment: Nice and very clean solution. Is there a way to get the length of the lists or break out of the loops, based on a conditional?

Comment: @saltypen: with package `xstring` you can check a given list: `\def\ListA{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}` 
`\StrCount{\ListA,}{,}[\Number]` 
The macro `\Number` returns 7

Comment: Please note, that this solution will create all combinations (two-dimensional set), whereas the question implies that only the pairs with the same index should be created (one-dimensional set). This might be a problem in some cases, as the variable aname2 would be unintentionally overwritten by the current solution, if it existed before.

Comment: @MMMM: Yiannis Lazarides seems to be happy if this requirement isn't met. I too thought he needed it.

Comment: @Herbert: `\psforeach` can't do auto-completion `\psforeach\A{a,...,g}`?

Comment: @AhmedMusa: that is only possible for numerical values

Answer (score 9):

You can map a function on two comma-separated list, using the code below. It also lets you "zip" two comma separated lists together. All this is expandable, e.g. suitable for use in a `\write` statement, etc. Or rather, it is expandable if the function you map is itself expandable. See the end of the code for an example suited to your case.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn 
% Spaces are now ignored, and `_` and `:` can be used in macro names.
%
% `\tl_if_either_empty_ii:nn` tests whether either one of two token
% lists is empty.
%
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \tl_if_either_empty_ii:nn #1 #2 {p,T,F,TF} {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {\prg_return_true:} {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2} {\prg_return_true:} {\prg_return_false:} 
  }
}

% Function to zip two clist together, e.g.,
%   {1,2,3,4,5} {aa,bb,cc,d} -> {1}{aa}, {2}{bb}, {3}{cc}, {4}{d}
% It stops when reaching the end of any of the two lists. For people who
% care: it is `f`-expandable.
%
\cs_new:Npn \clist_zip_ii:nn #1 #2 {
  \clist_zip_ii_aux:nw {} #1, \q_mark, #2, \q_mark.
}
\cs_new:Npn \clist_zip_ii_aux:nw #1 #2, #3 \q_mark, #4, #5 \q_mark. {
  \tl_if_either_empty_ii:nnTF {#3} {#5} {
    #1 {#2}{#4}
  }{
    \clist_zip_ii_aux:nw {#1 {#2}{#4},} #3 \q_mark, #5 \q_mark.
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_zip_ii:nn {VV}


% To map a function `#3` of two arguments onto the zipped result, 
% we do something similar, essentially replacing commas by `#1` in 
% the output.
\cs_new:Npn \clist_map_zip_ii:nnN #1 #2 #3 {
  \clist_map_zip_ii_aux:Nnw #3 {} #1, \q_mark, #2, \q_mark.
}
\cs_new:Npn \clist_map_zip_ii_aux:Nnw #1 #2 #3, #4 \q_mark, #5, #6 \q_mark. {
  \tl_if_either_empty_ii:nnTF {#4} {#6} {
    #2 #1{#3}{#5}
  }{
    \clist_map_zip_ii_aux:Nnw #1 {#2 #1{#3}{#5}} #4 \q_mark, #6 \q_mark.
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_zip_ii:nnN {VV}




% ======================= Your comma separated lists ==================
% All those `g` mean `global`.
\clist_new:N \g_my_first_clist
\clist_new:N \g_my_second_clist
\clist_gput_right:Nn \g_my_first_clist {a,b,c,d,e,f}
\clist_gput_right:Nn \g_my_second_clist {1,2,3,4,5}

\cs_new:Npn \my_create_variable:nn #1 #2 {
  \iow_term:n {Creating~variable~``#1 name #2''} % Message to the terminal
  \tl_new:c {#1 name #2}
}

\clist_map_zip_ii:VVN \g_my_first_clist 
                      \g_my_second_clist 
                      \my_create_variable:nn

% Restore the usual behaviour of space, colon and underscore.
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: zip with TeX. Now I've seen everything. :‑)

Comment: @morbusg. I'm still trying to figure out an efficient way of zipping `n` lists rather than `2`.

Comment: It is possible to implement a set of list operations like LISP language?

Comment: @Leo Liu. I don't know Lisp, but if you describe what you would like, I can code it.

Comment: Nice! In l3candidates I've also got a mapthread function for seqs using a non-expandable stack-based approach. Yours is better, I think, for most applications. P.S. Although it's kinda idiosyncratic, we use the "N" argument to denote a clist variable. Perhaps this was a bad decision, but it's consistent with seq.

Comment: @Will: Mine is expandable, but quadratic. Is the non-expandable version also quadratic? --- It could be nicer to `map_function` on the zipped clist. For that we need either a `map_function_unbraced`, which leaves the argument unbraced, or a `map_function:Nn` which maps a bunch of tokens rater than just a function (I'd prefer that.) Then `\clist_map_function:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\exp_after:wN \foo:nn \use:n}` will map a function of two variables on a zipped clist. --- Do you `generate_variant ... {V}` and then rename to `N`?

Comment: @bruno To be honest I haven't looked too much into the efficiency of the mapthread function; it works by popping items off the stack and passing the values to the mapping function; I suspect, but I'm not sure, it might be faster for large lists. For these faux-V functions, we just create them manually with \exp_args.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind global assignments and to interleave the lists you can use the `\foreach` macro of `pgffor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \name/\value in {namea/a,nameb/b,namec/c} {%
    \global\expandafter\def\csname\name\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\value}%
}
% Test:
\show\namea \show\nameb \show\namec
\end{document}
```

Otherwise you need to program you own loop which removes a value from each list. Just look e.g. how the `\@for` loop is defined in `latex.ltx`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using simple iteration. I'm sorry that the code is not very clean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\long\def\getfirst@#1,#2\@@#3{\def#3{#1}}
\long\def\getfirst#1#2{%
  \def\temp{#2}%
  \expandafter\getfirst@\temp,\@nil\@@#1}

\def\@nil@{\@nil}
\long\def\getrest@#1,#2\@@#3{\def\temp{#2}%
  \ifx\@nil@\temp
    \let#3\undefined
  \else
    \expandafter\getrest@@\temp#3
  \fi}
\long\def\getrest@@#1,\@nil#2{\def#2{#1}}
\long\def\getrest#1#2{%
  \def\temp{#2}%
  \expandafter\getrest@\temp,\@nil\@@#1}

\long\def\split#1#2#3{%
  \def\temp{#3}%
  \expandafter\getfirst@\temp,\@nil\@@#1
  \def\temp{#3}%
  \expandafter\getrest@\temp,\@nil\@@#2}

\begin{document}

% your list
\def\listA{a,b,c,d,e,f}
\def\listB{X,Y,Z,W}

\newif\ifloop
\def\testloop{%
  \ifx\listA\undefined \loopfalse \fi
  \ifx\listB\undefined \loopfalse \fi
  \ifloop}
\looptrue
\loop
% extract list
  \expandafter\split\expandafter\firstofA\expandafter\restofA\expandafter{\listA}
  \expandafter\split\expandafter\firstofB\expandafter\restofB\expandafter{\listB}
% show progress
  {\tt
  \meaning\firstofA \qquad \meaning\restofA\qquad
  \meaning\firstofB \qquad \meaning\restofB\par}%
% do definition
  \expandafter\edef \csname TT\firstofA\endcsname {\firstofB}%
% iteration
  \let\listA\restofA
  \let\listB\restofB
\testloop\repeat

result:\\
\verb=\TTa= is \TTa\\
\verb=\TTb= is \TTb\\
\verb=\TTc= is \TTc\\
\verb=\TTd= is \TTd

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the question is a bit older, the general problem still occurs from time to time. The following generic solution defines the macro `\forlistlooptwo`, which works as etoolbox' `\forlistloop`. There are two extensions: First, it expects two comma separated lists instead of one and second, the handler function expects two arguments instead of one.

Use lists of equal lengths and avoid spaces and semicolons in the lists and in the elements, respectively, as I wanted to keep the code short.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\forlistlooptwo#1#2#3{%
    \ifboolexpr{test{\IfSubStr{#2}{,}} and test{\IfSubStr{#3}{,}}}{%
        % Evaluate first pair and call back with reduced lists if there are at least two elements in each list..
        \forlistlooptwohelper{#1}#2;#3;%
    }{%
        \ifboolexpr{test{\notblank{#2}} and test{\notblank{#3}}}{%
            % Evaluate last pair, if there is one element in each list.
            #1{#2}{#3}%
        }{}%
    }%
}
\def\forlistlooptwohelper#1#2,#3;#4,#5;{%
    % Call the handler with the first pair as the two arguments.
    #1{#2}{#4}%
    % Call the loop macro again with the lists reduced by the first pair.
    \forlistlooptwo{#1}{#3}{#5}%
}

\begin{document}
    \def\createVariableFromPair#1#2{%
        \csdef{#1#2}{}%
    }%
    \forlistlooptwo{\createVariableFromPair}{a,b,c}{name1,name2,name3}%
    \ifcsdef{bname2}{true}{false}, \ifcsdef{bname3}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

The example outputs as demanded: true, false

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, `arrayjobx` package can do the trick, although the data are not separated by commas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{ind}

\begin{document}
\newarray\Names
\newarray\Primes

\readarray{Names}{two&three&five&seven&eleven}
\readarray{Primes}{2&3&5&7&11&13}

\noindent
\setcounter{ind}{1}%
\whiledo{\value{ind}<10}{%
% show progress
  \theind: \Names(\theind)---\Primes(\theind)\\
% do definitions
  \checkNames(\theind)\let\temp\cachedata
  \checkPrimes(\theind)%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname\temp\endcsname{\cachedata}%
% step index counter
  \stepcounter{ind}}

\two, \three, \five, \seven, \eleven

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that gives exit conditions as the OP indicated in the question. Also, active commas are welcome and spurious spaces in the list are trimmed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{loops}

\def\ftoks{f}

\newforeach \x [
  item counter = \xc, exit when = \ifx\x\ftoks\fi
] in {a,...,g} do {%
  \let\xcc\xc
  \newforeach [
    count in = \yc all \y satisfying \ifnum\y>10\fi,
    loop stopper = \ifnum\y>20\fi
  ] \y in {1,...,30} {%
    \skvcsdef{#1##1}{Items: #1, ##1}%
  }%
  \let\xc\xcc
}

\begin{document}
Numbers: {\tt\string\xc}: \xc, {\tt\string\yc}: \yc

\skvcsuse{a1}

\skvcsuse{e10}

\end{document}
```

[image]