# Iterating through comma-separated arguments

Tags: macros, comma-separated-list

I've looked all over and can't seem to find a succinct answer to this question.  Is it possible (and if so, how) to create a command that will iterate through its `arguments' of comma-separated values and act upon them?

Example mostly stolen from ["For loop" in newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20341/for-loop-in-newcommand):

```
\newcommand{\pdfappendix}[1]{
    for \image in #1
    {
       \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{\image.pdf}
    }
}
```

The goal here is to create a command that can print a file menu structure (or some arbitrary path) like so:

```
\ppath{Command,TeXing Options,Generate PDF (C-c C-t C-p)}
```

potentially with an optional argument for a delimiter (defaulting to `\to` or something)

which would produce

```
Command -> TeXing Options -> Generate PDF (C-c C-t C-p)
```

In the words of [holy `ed`](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html), `?`

Comment: There are plenty of questions for lists see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19761/963 and maybe you can post a more specific question

Comment: Can you explain in how far the answers in the questions you linked don't fulfil your needs?

Comment: For a more specific question, see [Understanding a \@for loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34995/2693).

Comment: It would also be beneficial to peruse the posts tagged with [tag:comma-separated-list].

Comment: Actually did that.  I'll go through them again - I skipped a few where I didn't foresee the general answer.

Comment: Bingo. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12187/iterating-through-two-lists)

Comment: I believe **menukeys** provides this functionality. Should it be helpfull to some one else.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s list processing capabilities are straight forward:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\ppath}[2][$\;\triangleright\;$]{%
  \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{#1}}% Separator
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\nextitem\textsf{##1}}% How to process each item
  \docsvlist{#2}% Process list
}
\begin{document}
A decent file path is \ppath{File,New,Document}.
\end{document}
```

The separator `\nextitem` is defined to do nothing during its first use. `\do` defines how each item is processed, while `\docsvlist` processes a comma-separated list. See [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764) for a short discussion on the use of `\nextitem`.

Comment: Very clever fix for the first item bit.

Comment: As highlighted in [adding \chapter in KOMA scrbook generates a “! LaTeX Error: \do undefined.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367418/64454), using the `\do` command might lead to errors because numerous other packages/macros redefines it (e.g. notably `\chapter` of KOMA's classes). *egreg* thus suggests [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367446/64454) a variant of this answer without using `\do`.

Comment: Is it possible to handle the last item differently like making `\ppah{a,b,c}` produce "a, b and c"?

Comment: @Mr.Ree: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/hMC8bmFk) ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R74Dq.png)).

Comment: @Werner Thanks for your nice code! I've only found some codes which are too complicated to understand before.

Answer (score 10):

Found an answer in [another question's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12192/17423).  With @Werner's [help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/17423) (specifically the deferred `\def` trick), the pure TeX solution works without the need for extra packages. What follows is a minimal working example of what I was looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ppath}[2][ $\triangleright$ ]{%
  \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{#1}}%
  \@for \el:=#2\do{\nextitem\el}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  A decent file path is \ppath{File,New,Why}.  I said, Why.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

(Thanks @Peter, @jon.)

---

Explanation for the comments:

`\def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{#1}}` here is defining `\nextitem` to, when it is used, redefine `\nextitem` to expand to the argument it was given the first time.  This is a pretty tricky operation, so read that again.

So, if I call `\nextitem{foo}`, that expands to `\def\nextitem{foo}`. The `\nextitem` token, having been consumed and expanded, is gone. Note that `\nextitem` goes from having one argument to having no arguments; after using `\nextitem{foo}`, that *itself* redefines `\nextitem` to `foo` -- and doesn't emit `foo` the first time (since the first time is just the redefinition.

This is heart of the trick: the for loop provides a way to output `>File>New>Why` -- the `\nextitem` trickery is a way to make the first `>` 'disappear' -- because the first time `\nextitem` is used, all it's doing is a redefinition.

Comment: You need to use  `\@for \el:=#2\do{\nextitem\el}%`. But this really should have been a separate question.

Comment: It looks like you forgot a `%` at the end of `line 6`: `\@for ... \el}%`.

Comment: I should have made it *far* more clear it was rhetorical (but I was actually about to ask a separate question, funnily enough).  That clears up on side of it, but not the other. I found that (in the original) the macro was padding the output with a single space.  It makes sense that your fix takes care of the one on the right and not on the left.  I'm wondering now if the `\def` is giving us an intermittent space for some reason.

Comment: Found it, and I'm dumb. Missed a `%` after the first line in my typeup. Edited.

Comment: I really like your solution @SeanAllred, but I'm baffled, I can't understand it. Could you explain what's happening here? What does `\def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{#1}}` do to `\nextitem`? And if `el:=#2`, then `\el` is simply the triangle and the for loop does one iteration?

Comment: @StevenHorstink It's been a long time since I exercised my TeX-fu, but I'll try to help. My explanation got kind of long, so I included it as an edit -- hopefully that helps!

Comment: @SeanAllred thanks for the quick reply. Tricky indeed, very clever. Your explanation made me realize now why I didn't understand: I mixed up the parameters, thinking #2 was the triangle. Now it all makes sense! Either way, clever solution, nice and simple.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with LaTeX3, which might be simpler

### Since may 2021

`\clist_use:nn` and `\clist_use:nnnn` are available as pointed out by `egreg` in the comments.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \ppath { O{$\;\triangleright\;$} m } {
  \clist_use:nn { #2 } { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
A decent file path is \ppath{File,New,Document}.
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

#### Before may 2021

The instruction `\clist_use:nn { #2 } { #1 }` should be replaced by

```
  \group_begin:
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 }
  \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  \group_end:
```

**Some explanations:**

In the second example,

1. We wrap the commands in a group to use local variables
2. We store the mandatory argument in a scratch variable named `\l_tmpa_clist` of type clist
3. We "use" that variable to display the list with the given separator

Notice the use of `\clist_use:Nn` instead of `\clist_use:nn`.

The LaTeX3 commands documentation is available on CTAN as interface3.pdf and may be available locally with `texdoc interface3`.

Comment: +1 This has also the advantage that spaces around commas will be ignored.

Comment: +1 Another advantage is that blankness/emptiness between commas will not lead to mapping to an empty element. I.e., with `\ppath{File, ,,New,Document,}`  neither you get three triangles behind "File" but you get only one triangle, nor you get a triangle behind "Document".

Comment: To be even more complete, one can use a void group `{}` to have a blank item that is not discarded: with `\ppath{File, {} ,{},New,Document,{}}` you obtain as many triangles as there are commas.

Comment: Since May 2021, it's no longer needed to set a variable, so the group is unnecessary and `\clist_use:nn { #2 } { #1 }` is even fully expandable.

Answer (score 1):

In OpTeX we have `\foreach` command with the syntax

```
\foreach <list of object>\do <parameter-mask for sigle object>{<what to do>}
```

For example

```
\foreach a,b,c,d,\do #1,{do something with #1}
```

does (expadable) loop over the given list of objects separated by comma. Your task should be solved by the following macro:

```
\def\ppath#1{\ppathA#1,\end}
\def\ppathA#1,#2\end{#1\foreach #2\do ##1,{$\,\triangleright\,$##1}}

\ppath{Command,TeXing Options,Generate PDF (C-c C-t C-p)}

\ppath{Cmd}

\bye
```