# Creating a newcommand with indefinite arguments

Tags: macros

I am kind of new to LaTeX. I am doing project which contain resources (formula, solutions to problems, e.g.) i can bring to the Exams day on 16th March. I have been looking for a solution to my problem couple of hours now. What i am trying to achieve is to create a `\newcommand` with indefinite variable (arguments?) that can do a repetitive task such as 5 `\times 10 \times 15 \times 20 \times 25`. The numbers are supposed to be the arguments and `\times`, the repeating task between each argument. I have tried to make a `tabular` many column inside a `\newcommand` but have not succeed. To give a better vision, i will post a piece of my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}

\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\setlength{\jot}{14pt}

\title{Hjelpermidler i Digital Radio}
\author{Sami Rashiti}

\newcommand{\degree}[2]{#1\,^{\circ}\ \mathrm{#2}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle 
\newpage

\section*{Innlevering 1}
\input{innleveringer/innlevering1.tex}
~\newline

\begin{align}
    e_n &= \sqrt{4KTBR}                                                                     \\
    e_n^2 &= 4KTBR                                                                          \\
    R &= \frac{e_n^2}{4KTB}                                                                 \\
      &= \frac{(\frac{V_o}{A})^2}{4KTB} \qquad ,der \quad e_n = \frac{V_o}{A} = 3,2\mu V    \\
      &= \frac{(3.2\mu V)^2}{4\cdot1.38\cdot 10^{-23}\cdot 310\cdot   100\cdot 10^3}        \\
      &= 6\ k\Omega
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use a list.

Comment: As an aside, check out the `siunitx` package for formatting your units.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a list; here's an example using [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and borrowing the idea for the first item in the list used by **Werner** in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/3954) to [Iterating through comma-separated arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87407/3954):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\Multiply[2][\cdot]{%
  \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{#1}}% Separator
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\nextitem##1}% How to process each item
  \docsvlist{#2}% Process list
}
\begin{document}

\[
\Multiply[\times]{4,1.38\cdot 10^{-23},310,100,10^3}\qquad
\Multiply{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As highlighted in [adding \chapter in KOMA scrbook generates a “! LaTeX Error: \do undefined.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367418/64454), using the `\do` command might lead to errors because numerous other packages/macros redefines it (e.g. notably `\chapter` of KOMA's classes). *egreg* thus suggests [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367446/64454) a variant of this answer without using `\do`.

Answer (score 8):

It's a breeze with `xparse` and `expl3`. Separate the items by a comma and that's all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\Multiply{O{\cdot}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #2 } % split the input at commas
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }              % put #1 between items
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\Multiply[\times]{4,1.38\cdot 10^{-23},310,100,10^3}$

$\Multiply{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that, differently from the other answers, this method removes spaces around the items. So with this method, inputting `\Multiply{ a , b}` is equivalent to inputting `\Multiply{a,b}`. It's not relevant in this case, because the macro works in math mode, but it can be very important in case of a macro used in normal text.

Answer (score 5):

The common method how to deal more arguments at TeX primitive level is:

```
\def\Multiply#1{\MultiplyA#1,,}
\def\MultiplyA#1,{#1\MultiplyB}
\def\MultiplyB#1,{\ifx,#1,\else\cdot#1\expandafter\MultiplyB\fi}

$$
\Multiply{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n}
$$

\end
```