# expl3: How to remove the final comma in a clist mapping

Tags: expl3, comma-separated-list

I want to process a clist, and I can't use `\clist_use:Nn` as I have to some rather complicated things with the items. But how do you remove the final separator without to much fuss when using `\clist_map_inline:Nn`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_const:Nn\c_UF_clist {a,b,c,d}

\clist_map_inline:Nn\c_UF_clist
{\textbf{#1},~} %no comma after d!!!!
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've seen egreg first poping the left item, and then use `{,~\textbf{#1}` mapping the rest of the `clist`. Still, I don't know what's the “official way”. May be something similar to `\seq_set_map:NNn \foo \bar {\textbf{#1}}` and then `\seq_use:Nn \foo {,~}`?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231743/5764) might be helpful - splitting the list *first*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This, seems to me, is natural, although a bit tedious. (I leave the `\seq_pop_left:NN` option for another answer).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { a , b , c , d }
\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \exp_not:n { \textbf { #1 } } }
\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { ,~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

In case you can't use `\seq_set_map:NNn` because of its experimentalness, you can define your own function

```
\seq_new:N \l__map_and_use_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \uf_seq_map_use:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__map_and_use_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn #1 { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__map_and_use_seq { #2 } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__map_and_use_seq { #3 }
 }

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { a , b , c , d }    
\uf_seq_map_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \textbf { [#1] } } { ,~ }
```

Or even clist directly if you prefer

```
\seq_new:N \l__map_and_use_seq
\seq_new:N \l__set_and_map_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \uf_clist_map_use:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__map_and_use_seq
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__set_and_map_seq { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__set_and_map_seq { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__map_and_use_seq { #2 } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__map_and_use_seq { #3 }
 }

\uf_clist_map_use:nnn { a , b , c , d } { \textbf { [#1] } } { ,~ }
```

Comment: This looks quite natural (apart from the fact that one has to convert to a sequence first, perhaps I should create sequences from start), but I can't use `\seq_set_map:NNn` as it is marked as "experimental" in source3.pdf.

Comment: You could declare a new function.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Part of the reason for having experimental functions is to see if they are useful! We don't remove stuff unless we have first checked for use in TeX Live.

Comment: @JosephWright: The code will be in a class of a customer. It will be never seen by texlive or CTAN. And I agree with egreg that more "use"-functions would be useful. It is imho very natural (in typesetting) that you want to do something different with the first and the last item of a list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Non-released code is of course a bit more tricky, but the point 'if it doesn't get tested we don't know it's useful' remains true! The present `use` functions are not exactly for typesetting or at least not focussed exclusively on that area. However, I can see the point: I need to work out the naming, _etc._

Comment: Well now I really have the choice ;-).

Answer (score 8):

Without using sequences, you can pop the leftmost item in the clist and map the remaining clist:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__UF_clist_use_head_tl
\clist_new:N \l__UF_clist_use_tail_clist
\cs_new_protected:Npn \UF_clist_use:NNn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \clist_set_eq:NN \l__UF_clist_use_tail_clist #1
  \clist_pop:NN \l__UF_clist_use_tail_tl \l__UF_clist_use_head_tl
  \exp_args:NV #2 \l__UF_clist_use_head_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__UF_clist_use_tail_clist
   {
    #3 #2 { ##1 }
   }
 }

\clist_const:Nn \c_UF_clist {a,b,c,d}

\begin{document}

\UF_clist_use:NNn \c_UF_clist \textbf { ,~ }

\end{document}
```

The first argument of `\UF_clist_xuse:NNn` is a clist variable, the second argument is a one parameter function (here `\textbf`) and the third argument is the separator between arguments. This function can't be nested, but it doesn't seem to be a big limitation.

[image]

If you plan to emulate `\clist_use:Nnnn`, then transforming the clist into a sequence and applying `\seq_set_map:NNn` seems the best approach.

Kernel functions called `\seq_use:NNnnn`, `\seq_use:NNn`, `\clist_use:NNnnn` and `\clist_use:NNn`, where the second argument is a one parameter function to be applied to each item, would be welcome, in my opinion (even if they aren't fully expandable).

Comment: I'll take a look at the suggested `use:NN` syntax at some point

Comment: Thanks. This works fine too. I accepted the one from Manual as it is more in the spirit of "natural and not much fuss", at least more (in my eyes) than "popping something to the left, to avoid something on the right".

Comment: Wouldn't if be cleaner to use a clist for the tail-part instead of a token list?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oops!