# Select largest value from a list of variables in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals, siunitx, comma-separated-list, fp

I am trying to adapt this example [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list) as my base.  Except, rather than display all values, I actually want to iterate through all the values and only return / display the largest one.

The list of numbers I actually want to pass to a custom function will actually be `glossaries` labels.  I have tested it and I can insert `\gls{label}` into a command like 
`\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } {\glsentryname{##1} }` This works right away to display a list of my expanded values (which are actually numbers) so I am not worried about this part.

I haven't been able to figure out yet:

1. How can I stop this function from typsetting the text, but rather allow me to iterate through the list update a variable only displaying the final value?

   - For example at the start of the loop I would set a dummy value such as -100000
   - and the comparison would compare `##1` iteratively with the dummy variable.
   - With a function call such as a call to my macro `\pickGE` included below I would then return and update the value if the value in the list is greater than the dummy.
2. What approach would be appropriate to setup a dummmy variable that can be updated in this context
3. How would I finally report this final selected value.

   - I would like to wrap this final value in a `\num[scientific-notation = fixed, fixed-exponent = 0, group-digits=false]{}` call.

The complete MWE I want to insert

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\findLargest}{ m }
 {
  \begin{enumerate}
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \item \fbox{##1} }
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\pickGE}[2]{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdimgreater{{#1} pt}{{#2} pt}}}%
    {%
        \FPeval{result}{{#1}}%
    }% true
    {%
        \FPeval{result}{{#2}}%
    }% false
}


\begin{document}

\findLargest{1, 2 ,3 6, 3,1}

\end{document}
```

**Limitations**

- I am committed to using `XeLaTeX`
- I may be misremembering but I also have a vague recollection that `siunitx` had something to do this directly...
- I am happy to use any other package or approach much like the one employed here (that I wasn't able to make work with my glossaries labels [Iterating through comma-separated arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87407/iterating-through-comma-separated-arguments)
- I am not limited to only comma separated lists but based on the shear volume of questions this looked like a good way to go.

Comment: A quick peruse of the package pgfplotstable http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.pdf showed me that it can input from csv format and can find the max of values inputted.  I have not used this package and only spend about 3 minutes looking for a possible tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `max` function provided by `expl3` in the `fp` module:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\findLargest}{ om }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {% separator is a comma, directly use \fp_eval:n { max ( #2 ) }
    \engbird_compute_max:n { #2 }
   }
   {% we need to pass the separator
    \engbird_find_largest:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_engbird_largest_seq
\tl_new:N \l_engbird_largest_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \engbird_find_largest:nn #1 #2
 {
  % split the input at the stated separator
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_engbird_largest_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  % build a comma separated list
  \tl_set:Nx \l_engbird_largest_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_engbird_largest_seq {,} }
  % compute the max
  \engbird_compute_max:V \l_engbird_largest_tl
 }
% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Npn \engbird_compute_max:n #1
 {
  \fp_eval:n { max (#1) }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \engbird_compute_max:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\findLargest{1, 2 ,3, 6, 3,1}

\findLargest[;]{ 1.5 ; sqrt(2) ; pi/2 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `\num` and you don't need different separators, here's a way, that also allows to override the options passed by default to `\num`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\findLargest}{ O{}m }
 {
  \num[
    scientific-notation = fixed,
    fixed-exponent = 0,
    group-digits=false,
    #1
  ] { \engbird_compute_max:n { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \engbird_find_largest:nn #1 #2
 {
  \engbird_compute_max:V \l_engbird_largest_tl
 }
% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Npn \engbird_compute_max:n #1
 {
  \fp_eval:n { max (#1) }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \engbird_compute_max:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\findLargest{1, 2 ,3, 6, 3,1}

\findLargest[group-digits=true]{10000,20000}

\findLargest[round-mode=places]{ 1.5, sqrt(2), pi/2 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly.  I checked `xparse` for documentation but didn't find anything about `\cs` type structure.  Where can I go to learn more about this syntax?

Comment: @EngBIRD You should do `texdoc expl3`

Comment: Awesome, I will look into this. One more small question. When I am programming in a language that doesn't handle scope well, or has limited capabilities to update or redefine the variable in function arguments, I prefer to save to a variable that will be able to be updated and remain accessible without posing scope problems. Eg. in this answer makes continuous reference to `#1` and `#2`.  If I were to expand these functions to more dynamically process 1 and 2 and update their values would I be correct in assuming that `#1` can't be updated, but could be copied into another defined variable?

Comment: @EngBIRD I couldn't understand a word, sorry.

Comment: My preferred approach upon entering a custom function or macro would be to use the current index (i.e element of the string parsed and subsequently iterated through) to another variable, i.e. `tmp` so that it can be used in decisions prior to the `max(#2)` evaluation itself.  Specifically, I might want to parse the `#2` or `tmp` to determine if it is a valid `gls` label so that I can accept manually entered numbers as well as numbers retrieved by gls.  If a glslabel is found, I would update the variable with the result of `glsentryname{tmp}`

Comment: @EngBIRD Sorry, but this is too vague. What has `\glsentryname` to do with `\num`?

Comment: My apologies.  I will post this as a distinct and new question, I wasn't able to provide sufficient details in the short comments.  Sorry for the confusion but thank you for your consideration.