# Handling _ (underscores) in a macro's comma-separated list of arguments

Tags: symbols, comma-separated-list, arguments

**Context:** I created a "`\citep`-like" macro. I use it in the body of my document to refer to some code found in appendix.

My macro takes a comma-separated list as input, and prints each element of the list as an `hyperref` link to the relevant part of the code. (To make things easy, the text of the `hyperref` link is the key itself, and the syntax of link's anchor is `code:<key>`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \newcommand{\codecitep}[1]{% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/64454
        [%
        \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}% Separator
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\nextitem{\hyperref[code:##1]{##1}}}% How to process each item
        \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
        ]%
    }   
\begin{document}
    \section{Body}
        A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{key1}.
        Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by dummy text \codecitep{key1, key2}.
%       A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{a_123}.
%       Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by dummy text \codecitep{a_123, bb_456}.

        \lipsum[1-2]

    \section{Appendix}
        \lipsum[3]

        \subsection{key1}
        \label{code:key1}
        \label{code:a_123}
        \lipsum[4]

        \subsection{key2}
        \label{code:key2}
        \label{code:bb_456}
        \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

**Problem:** 
The MWE above works great. However, my real-case keys have following structure: `a_123`, `bb_456`, etc. (I.e. there is an underscore in the middle of the key, and the number of letters before it is unknown.)
Of course this makes compilation fail since the underscore is neither escaped nor in a math environment.

**Question:** How to handle keys with underscore in my comma-separated list of argument of my macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\detokenize`; but if you want a *printed* underscore, you need to load `fontenc` with the `T1` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\codecitep}[1]{% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/64454
  [%
  \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}% Separator
  % How to process each item
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \nextitem\hyperref[code:##1]{\detokenize{##1}}%
  }%
  \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
  ]%
}   
\begin{document}

\section{Body}
A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{key1}.
Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by dummy text \codecitep{key1, key2}.
A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{a_123}.
Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by dummy text \codecitep{a_123, bb_456}.

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Appendix}
\lipsum[3]

\subsection{key1}
\label{code:key1}
\label{code:a_123}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{key2}
\label{code:key2}
\label{code:bb_456}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an `expl3` version, which doesn't need `fontenc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% define a token list containing an underscore
\tl_const:Nx \c_ebo_codecite_us_tl { \char_generate:nn { `_ } { 8 } }

% the main macro
\NewDocumentCommand{\codecitep}{m}
 {
  \ebo_codecite:n { #1 }
 }

% variables and variants of kernel functions
\tl_new:N \l__ebo_codecite_key_print_tl
\seq_new:N \l__ebo_codecite_refs_seq

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { NV }

% functions

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ebo_codecite:n
 {
  [
   % clear the sequence
   \seq_clear:N \l__ebo_codecite_refs_seq
   % loop through the input
   \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
     % for the "print part", change _ into \_
     \tl_set:Nn \l__ebo_codecite_key_print_tl { ##1 }
     \tl_replace_all:NVn \l__ebo_codecite_key_print_tl \c_ebo_codecite_us_tl { \_ }
     % add to the sequence
     \__ebo_codecitep_add:nV { ##1 } \l__ebo_codecite_key_print_tl
    }
   % use the sequence, items separated by "comma space"
   \seq_use:Nn \l__ebo_codecite_refs_seq { ,~ }
  ]
 }

% an auxiliary function, for expanding the second argument
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ebo_codecitep_add:nn
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__ebo_codecite_refs_seq { \hyperref[code:#1]{#2} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ebo_codecitep_add:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Body}
A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{key1}.
Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by dummy text \codecitep{key1, key2}.
A sentence with one code-citation only \codecitep{a_123}.
Another sentence with two code-citations and followed by dummy text \codecitep{a_123, bb_456}.

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Appendix}
\lipsum[3]

\subsection{key1}
\label{code:key1}
\label{code:a_123}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{key2}
\label{code:key2}
\label{code:bb_456}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do this is to load the `url` package and define a url command to format the refnames:

```
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand{\coderefname}{\urlstyle{rm}}

\newcommand{\codecitep}[1]{% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/64454
    [%
    \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}% Separator
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\nextitem{\hyperref[code:##1]{\coderefname{##1}}}}% How to process each item
    \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
    ]%
}
```