# Hyphenation after _ underscore in an detokenized string

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, hyphenation, detokenize

**Context:** In my document, I use a citation mechanism for personal references. I defined a `\citeref{}` macro that processes a comma-separated list of arguments. The latter have following structure: `abc_123`. The purpose of the `\citeref` macro
is to iterate over the list of arguments, do some black magic (not represented in the MWE), and finally print the list of arguments within squared brackets. Because there is an underscore in the references, I `\detokenize` them in order to typeset them.

**Problem:** The hyphenation of the `abc_123`-like references is not optimal. Notably, no line break is enabled after the underscore `_`. Yet using the `hyphenat` package is not effective, as the string is detokenized.

**Question:** How to enable line break/hyphenation after an underscore inside a detokenized string?

---

**MWE**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \newcommand{\citeref}[1]{
        % cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/64454; https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367418/64454
        [%
            \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}% Separator
            \forcsvlist\citerefitem{#1}% Process list
        ]%
    }
    \newcommand{\citerefitem}[1]{%
        \nextitem
        \detokenize{#1}%
    }

    \usepackage{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
    Usually, it works fine: either for single \dots\dots\dots\dots\citeref{abcabc_123} or for multiple references \dots\dots\dots\dots\citeref{abc_123, def_456}.

    However, for longer references, a hyphenation would be welcome after the underscore: \citeref{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_12345678910111213}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: I could change `abc_123` into `abc\_123`: this would enable me to use `hyphenat` as is and not use `\detokenize`. However, I don't want this solution as my "black magic" notably consists in writing this reference into an external file for later processing.

Comment: Are you tied to `etoolbox`?

Comment: My only constraint is that I'm close to the deadline of my thesis (hence the tracking of overfull boxes) `(-;`.

Comment: @egreg The most critical part of the "black magic" is only a `\immediate\write\tempfile{#1}`. So I suppose any other way to process a comma-separated list would be ok.

Comment: I found some recent code for an answer to a question of yours; it would be very easy to change it so that instead of `\_` the code substitutes something like `\_\allowbreak`

Comment: @egreg Which question are you referring to? As far as I've understood `\usepackage{hyphenat} + \_` = `\_\allowbreak`. However, I would prefer not change my `abc_123` into `abc\_123` (or `abc\_\allowbreak 123`), as I would like to have the string `abc_123` to be written in my temporary file without backslash...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367414/4427

Comment: @egreg Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62319/discussion-between-ebo-and-egreg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `url` package instead of `\detokenize`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{url}
    \DeclareUrlCommand\citerefurl{\urlstyle{same}}
    \newcommand{\citeref}[1]{
        % cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/64454; https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367418/64454
        [%
            \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}% Separator
            \forcsvlist\citerefitem{#1}% Process list
        ]%
    }
    \newcommand{\citerefitem}[1]{%
        \nextitem
        \citerefurl{#1}%
    }

    \usepackage{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
    Usually, it works fine: either for single \dots\dots\dots\dots\citeref{abcabc_123} or for multiple references \dots\dots\dots\dots\citeref{abc_123, def_456}.

    However, for longer references, a hyphenation would be welcome after the underscore: \citeref{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_12345678910111213}.
\end{document}
```

[image]