# Alternative to detokenize working with special unicode characters

Tags: unicode, detokenize

I have defined new command using `\NewDocumentCommand` which represents description of node in graph. This contains **name** (provided as argument), some text **description** (provided as argument) and **links** to other nodes (specified as semicolon separated list of **name**s in argument). From answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367411/handling-underscores-in-a-macros-comma-separated-list-of-arguments) question, I have discovered `\detokenize` command, which allows me to properly display node **name**s containing underscores. (Also I use this in `\paragraph` names, `\label` names and `\ref`erences.)

Problem is, when I use `\detokenize` on text description, some Unicode characters are replaced with wrong characters. (For example, `softvér` gets replaced by `softvŠr`.) Is there some alternative to `\detokenize`? I only need to automatically escape `<` and `>` that are present in some descriptions. I could use `\textless` and `textgreater`, but I had to use `detokenize` for names (so that referencing would work, I could not escape it properly as it is argument of macro), so I would like to have some consistency and provide **description** un-escaped.

**edit**
here is small example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\linespread{1.25}

\NewDocumentCommand\mynode{mm>{\SplitList{;}}m>{\SplitList{;}}m}
{
    \paragraph[\detokenize{#1}]{\detokenize{#2} (\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}):}
    \label{\detokenize{#1}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item vstupné hrany:
        \ProcessList{#3}{ \insertdep }
        \item výstupné hrany:
        \ProcessList{#4}{ \insertdep }
    \end{itemize}
}
\newcommand{\insertdep}[1]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{}{#1}}{\texttt{-}}{\texttt{\nameref{\detokenize{#1}}};}
}

\begin{document}
\mynode{root}{Koreň}{root}{gui}
\mynode{gui}{Grafické rozhranie}{root}{nice_gui;fancy_gui}
\mynode{nice_gui}{Pekné grafické rozhranie}{gui}{}
\mynode{fancy_gui}{This text contains less and greater characters:<>}{gui}{}
\end{document}
```

`\detokenize{#2}` breaks special Slovak characters (compared to using only `#2`). I have noticed, that it does not even fix problems with `_<>`. I have noticed, that when I use `\verb|#2|` instead of `\detokenize{#2}`, Slovak characters and `<>` work, but it obviously changes formatting and for some reason adds `|` at the end of text, and underscores still make latex to insert math mode and make subscript.

I'm using `pdflatex` to compile.

Comment: your question is not that clear, you can use `_`, `<` and `>` in label names without needing to do anything, `\label{foo_bar}`... `\ref{foo_bar}` works.

Comment: Show a complete minimal example, and also say how you are compiling (pdftex or luatex)

Comment: I have added small working example at the end of post. I have tried to remove any unnecessary `usepackage` commands. Sorry if some are left.

Comment: as you have seen, `\detokenize`  completely disables latex's encoding support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than using `\detokenize`, particularly with `IL2`. By the way, do you really need it?

Here's a way that preprocesses the input so to change `_<>` into proper commands.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\mynode{mmmm}
 {
  \mynode_main:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mynode_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mynode_output_seq
\tl_new:N \l_mynode_node_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mynode_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_main:nnnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mynode_input_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mynode_output_seq { ; } { #4 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_node_tl { #1 }
  \mynode_replace:N \l_mynode_node_tl
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_text_tl { #2 }
  \mynode_replace:N \l_mynode_text_tl

  \mynode_paragraph:VV \l_mynode_node_tl \l_mynode_text_tl
  \label{ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }

  \begin{itemize}
    \item vstupné~hrany:~
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_mynode_input_seq \l_mynode_node_tl
     {
      \mynode_print:N \l_mynode_node_tl
     }
    \item výstupné~hrany:~
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_mynode_output_seq \l_mynode_node_tl
     {
      \mynode_print:N \l_mynode_node_tl
     }
  \end{itemize}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_paragraph:nn
 {
  \paragraph[#1]{#2~(\texttt{#1}):}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mynode_paragraph:nn { VV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_print:N
 {
  \texttt
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF #1
      { - }
      { \nameref { \tl_to_str:N #1 } }
   };~
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_replace:N
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \_ } { \c{_} } #1
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \< } { \c{textless} } #1
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \> } { \c{textgreater} } #1
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\change}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_text_tl { #1 }
  \mynode_replace:N \l_mynode_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_mynode_text_tl
  %\tl_analysis_show:N #1 %%% for debugging
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mynode{root}{Koreň}{root}{gui}

\mynode{gui}{Grafické rozhranie}{root}{nice_gui;fancy_gui}

\mynode{nice_gui}{Pekné grafické rozhranie}{gui}{}

\mynode{fancy_gui}{This text contains less and greater characters:<>}{gui}{}

\mynode{<test>}{Some text with \texttt{under_score}}{<test>}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to LaTeX3 syntax, but it seems to work. One problem is, that this syntax uses `~` and spaces differently, so it breaks preprocessor called *Vlna*. (It inserts non-breakable space (`~`) after prepositions. In Slovak and Czech languages, you can't put preposition at the end of line, so I have to use it). I set my compile sequence in a way so that `main.tex` is not processed by `Vlna` and now everything works.

Comment: I have tested your provided example, and it breaks, when I put _ into second argument of \mynode. It throws error, missing $ inserted and considers rest of line as math.

Comment: @user224348 I assumed the text in the second argument was free of underscores. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have two separate problems: one with *font* encoding and one with *text* encoding. Unfortunately, I can help you only with the second one.

`\detokenize` is not UTF8-friendly, but sometimes you can replace it with the following command:

```latex
\newcommand{\utffriendlydetokenize}[1]{%
\scantokens{%
\catcode`\_=12%
\catcode`\^=12%
\catcode`\{=12%
\catcode`\}=12%
\catcode`\&=12%
\catcode`\$=12%
\catcode`\#=12%
\catcode`\~=12%
\catcode`\\=12%
#1%
}%
}
```

(source: https://gitlab.com/Nickkolok/biblatex2bibitem/-/blob/master/biblatex2bibitem.sty)

In your case the only row that should be changed is:

```latex
\paragraph[\detokenize{#1}]{\utffriendlydetokenize{#2} (\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}):}
```

And you get your `ň` back:
[image: result of patch]

However, it does not fix the problem with `<>_`, because the problem is caused by the codes of the symbols in specified `fontenc`. (See also [Strange behaviour with \detokenize and underscore](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150767/strange-behaviour-with-detokenize-and-underscore))
The only additional solution that  can guess about is to redefine `_<>` to be active characters by playing with their `catcode`s, to map them to the corresponding commands and to correct the definition `\utffriendlydetokenize` for the chosen `catcode`s.