# Centering list item justified and list in center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

I am not an expert on Latex, which is the reason I have used a template for my CV. Now I am struggling centering my list item text (left-to-right or justified) as outlined by the picture below.

There are two solutions I am looking for:

- One: Align my list items justified (left-to-right) (as depicted by 1 in the picture below)
- Two: Align the entire list in the center, with my list items justified (having the same distance as (2) in both right and left of my page)

**Note**: This snippet of code doesn't describe the entire content of the picture, which was done in order to prevent cluttered code on my post. Since I have used a template, I would expect you to ask for more information.

```
%% Used here mainly to get the effect of a shorter line under Projects
\columnratio{.9}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\cvsection{Projects}

\cvevent{Game Engine in C++ \& Lua - Blink}{Personal}{in progress}{}
\begin{itemize}

\item Used \textbf{spdlog} for my custom Logging System, which supports both the Game Engine Library and the Sandbox Application. Designed an Event System, described by a dispatcher which support keyboard, application and mouse events. Moreover, I have added an Input Polling System that queries client's actions and acts appropriately.

\item Architected a simple platform agnostic RenderAPI wrapper that currently supports OpenGL calls, but in the future will hopefully handle Vulkan and DirectX12 as well. Used \textbf{glm} as my OpenGL Mathematics Library since it complies with the column-major specification. 

\item \textbf{Other}: Created Vertex Buffer Layouts, Shaders, Materials, Orthographic Cameras

\end{itemize}

\end{paracol}
```

*EDIT:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This is altacv.cls (v1.3.2, 17 May 2020) written by
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com).
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%
%%
% Contributions:
% - https://github.com/akreuzer Added ragged2e option (5 Nov 2018)
% - https://github.com/stefanogermano Fixed bad boxes and undefined font shape (July 2018)
% - https://github.com/foohyfooh Fixed blank spaces in \cvevent and bad link in README.md (June 2018)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{altacv}[2020/05/17 AltaCV v1.3.2, yet another alternative class for a resume/curriculum vitae.]

%% v1.1: Optionally load academicons
\newif\if@academicons
\DeclareOption{academicons}{\@academiconstrue}
%% v1.1.3: Choice of round/square photo
\newif\if@normalphoto
\DeclareOption{normalphoto}{\@normalphototrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\newif\if@raggedtwoe
\DeclareOption{ragged2e}{\@raggedtwoetrue}
%% v1.3: load hyperref for clickable hyperlinks
\newif\if@withhyper
\DeclareOption{withhyper}{\@withhypertrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{article}
%% v1.3.2 Hopefully this helps make the PDF
%% file more 'friendly' with copy-paste etc
\RequirePackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

%% v1.1.5: added for convenience
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\ifxetexorluatex
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
\else
  %% v1.3.2 attempts to make ligatures
  %% copy-paste as normal characters
  \RequirePackage{cmap}
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \input{glyphtounicode}
  \pdfglyphtounicode{f_f}{FB00}
  \pdfglyphtounicode{f_f_i}{FB03}
  \pdfglyphtounicode{f_f_l}{FB04}
  \pdfglyphtounicode{f_i}{FB01}
  \pdfgentounicode=1
\fi

%% v1.1: Optionally load academicons
%% v1.1.5: Handle different versions of academicons
\if@academicons
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    %% academicons in TL2018 doesn't require
    %% Academicons to be installed in OS fonts
    %% so can be loaded directly
    \@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{%
      \RequirePackage{academicons}
    }{%
      % TL2017
      \@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2017/04/01}{%
        \@ifpackagelater{academicons}{2018/03/01}{%
          \RequirePackage{academicons}
        }{%
          \let\ori@newfontfamily\newfontfamily%
          \renewcommand{\newfontfamily}[2]{}
          \RequirePackage{academicons}
          \let\newfontfamily\ori@newfontfamily
          \newfontfamily{\AI}{academicons.ttf}
        }
      }{% TL2016 requires the package to be loaded before
        % the version can be checked. Only added because
        % Overleaf v1 still runs TL2016; will be removed
        % when v1 is completely retired.
          \let\ori@newfontfamily\newfontfamily%
          \renewcommand{\newfontfamily}[2]{}
          \RequirePackage{academicons}
          \let\newfontfamily\ori@newfontfamily
          \newfontfamily{\AI}{academicons.ttf}
      }
    }
  \else
    \ClassError{AltaCV}{academicons unsupported by latex or pdflatex. Please compile with xelatex or lualatex}{Please compile with xelatex or lualatex to use the academicons option}
  \fi
\fi

\if@raggedtwoe
  \RequirePackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\fi

\if@withhyper
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \RequirePackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}
    \urlstyle{same}
  }
\fi

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{heading}{black}
\colorlet{headingrule}{black}
\colorlet{subheading}{emphasis}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
\colorlet{name}{heading}
\colorlet{tagline}{accent}
\newcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\newcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,labelsep=0.5em,nosep,itemsep=0.25\baselineskip,after=\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\itemmarker}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{multirow,tabularx}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
% \RequirePackage{marginfix}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\divider}{\textcolor{body!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}

%% v1.3.1 \detokenize will break UTF-8 in pdflatex
%% Using alternative from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530911/226
\newcommand{\utffriendlydetokenize}[1]{%
\scantokens{%
  \catcode`\_=12%
%   \catcode`\^=12%
%   \catcode`\{=12%
%   \catcode`\}=12%
  \catcode`\&=12%
  \catcode`\$=12%
  \catcode`\#=12%
  \catcode`\~=12%
%   \catcode`\\=12%
  {#1}%
}%
}
%% v1.3: Incorporating hyperlinks
%% v1.3.1: using \unfriendlydetokenize to avoid
%% breaking unicode
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printinfo}{m m o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
    \mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}~\utffriendlydetokenize{#2}\hspace{2em}}%
  }{%
     \if@withhyper%
      \mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}~
      \href{#3}{\utffriendlydetokenize{#2}}\hspace{2em}}
     \else%
       \ClassWarning{Please specify [withhyper] option to enable hyperlinks. Printing out full hyperlink prefix #1 for now.}%
      \mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}~{\utffriendlydetokenize{#3#2}}\hspace{2em}}%
     \fi%
  }%
}%

%% v1.3: Exploring convenient creation of fields
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewInfoField}{m m o}{%
  \IfNoValueF{#3}{\csdef{#1 hyperprefix}{#3}}%
  \csdef{#1 symbol}{#2}%
  \csdef{#1}##1{%
    \if@withhyper
      \IfNoValueTF {#3}
        {\printinfo{\csuse{#1 symbol}}{##1}}%
        {\printinfo{\csuse{#1 symbol}}{##1}[\csuse{#1 hyperprefix}##1]}%
    \else
      \printinfo{\csuse{#1 symbol}}{##1}%
    \fi%
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\@name{#1}}
\newcommand{\tagline}[1]{\def\@tagline{#1}}
\newcommand{\personalinfo}[1]{\def\@personalinfo{#1}}
\NewInfoField{email}{\faAt}[mailto:]
\NewInfoField{mailaddress}{\faEnvelope}
\NewInfoField{phone}{\faPhone}
\NewInfoField{homepage}{\faGlobe}[https://]
\NewInfoField{twitter}{\faTwitter}[https://twitter.com/]
\NewInfoField{linkedin}{\faLinkedin}[https://linkedin.com/in/]
\NewInfoField{github}{\faGithub}[https://github.com/]
\NewInfoField{orcid}{\aiOrcid}[https://orcid.com/]
\NewInfoField{location}{\faMapMarker}

% v1.2: Support for multiple photos
\newlength{\altacv@photos@width}
\newlength{\altacv@photo@diam@left}
\newlength{\altacv@photo@diam@right}
\def\altacv@left@photos{}
\def\altacv@right@photos{}

\newcommand{\@makeaphoto}[2]{%
  \begin{minipage}{#1}%
    \if@normalphoto
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}
    \else
      \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={#2}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];
    \fi%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\newcommand{\altacv@add@photo@left}[1]{%
  \appto{\altacv@left@photos}{%
    \@makeaphoto{\altacv@photo@diam@left}{#1}\hspace{1ex}%
  }%
  \addtolength{\altacv@photos@width}{\altacv@photo@diam@left}%
  \addtolength{\altacv@photos@width}{1ex}%
}
\newcommand{\altacv@add@photo@right}[1]{%
  \appto{\altacv@right@photos}{%
    \@makeaphoto{\altacv@photo@diam@right}{#1}\hspace{1ex}%
  }%
  \addtolength{\altacv@photos@width}{\altacv@photo@diam@right}%
  \addtolength{\altacv@photos@width}{1ex}%
}
\newcommand{\photoL}[2]{%
  \setlength{\altacv@photo@diam@left}{#1}%
  \forcsvlist{\altacv@add@photo@left}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\photoR}[2]{%
  \setlength{\altacv@photo@diam@right}{#1}%
  \forcsvlist{\altacv@add@photo@right}{#2}%
}
\let\photo\photoR

\newcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\bfseries}
\newcommand{\taglinefont}{\large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\personalinfofont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\newcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\newcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}

\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \altacv@left@photos\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\altacv@photos@width}%
    \raggedright%
    {\namefont\color{name}\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
    \medskip
    {\taglinefont\color{tagline}\@tagline\par}
    \medskip
    {\personalinfofont\@personalinfo\par}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \altacv@right@photos\par%

  \endgroup\medskip
}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\color{accent}\itshape\large}{\par}

\newcommand{\cvsection}[2][]{%
  \bigskip%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\marginpar{\vspace*{\dimexpr1pt-\baselineskip}\raggedright\input{#1}}}%
  {\color{heading}\cvsectionfont\MakeUppercase{#2}}\\[-1ex]%
  {\color{headingrule}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par}\medskip
}

\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{%
  \smallskip%
  {\color{subheading}\cvsubsectionfont{#1}\par}\medskip
}

% v1.1.4: fixes inconsistent font size
\newcommand{\cvevent}[4]{%
  {\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}\par
  \smallskip}
  \ifstrequal{#3}{}{}{{\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{ \faCalendar ~#3}}}%
  \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{{\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{~#4}}}\par
  \medskip\normalsize
}

\newcommand{\cvachievement}[3]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{2em} @{\hspace{1ex}} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}}
  \multirow{2}{*}{\Large\color{accent}#1} & \bfseries\textcolor{emphasis}{#2}\\
  & #3
  \end{tabularx}%
  \smallskip
}

\newcommand{\cvtag}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=body!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.75ex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}

\newcommand{\cvskill}[2]{%
\textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\hfill
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{%
  \space{\ifnumgreater{\x}{#2}{\color{body!30}}{\color{accent}}\ratingmarker}}\par%
}

% Adapted from @Jake's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82729/226
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[4][0]{%
    \begingroup\centering
    \def\innerradius{#3}%
    \def\outerradius{#2}%
    % Calculate total
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}%
    \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#4} {%
        \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}%
        \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult%
    }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalrot}{-90 + #1}

      % Rotate so we start from the top
      \begin{scope}[rotate=\totalrot]

      % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
      \foreach \value/\width/\colour/\name in {#4} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

            % Calculate the percent value
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
            % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

            % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
            \pgfmathparse{
               (-\midangle>180?"west":"east")
            } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathparse{
               (-\midangle>180?"flush left":"flush right")
            } \edef\textalign{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle<180)}

            % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
            \filldraw[draw=white,fill=\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
            (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

            % Draw the data labels
            \draw  [*-,thin,emphasis] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=1ex, outer sep=0pt, text width=\width,anchor=\textanchor,align=\textalign,font=\small,text=body]{\name};
            % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
            \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }
      \end{scope}
%      \draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
    \end{tikzpicture}\par
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\cvref}[3]{%
  \smallskip
  \textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\par
  \begin{description}[font=\color{accent},style=multiline,leftmargin=1.35em,align=left]
  \item[\small\normalfont\emailsymbol] #2
  \item[\small\normalfont\mailaddresssymbol] #3
  \end{description}
%   \medskip
}

\newenvironment{cvcolumn}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\raggedright}{\end{minipage}}

\RequirePackage[style=apa6,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
%% For removing numbering entirely when using a numeric style
% \setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
% \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
% \setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\defbibheading{pubtype}{\cvsubsection{#1}}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.25\baselineskip}

% v1.1.2: make it easier to add a sidebar aligned with top of next page
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\addsidebar}[2][]{\marginpar{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\vspace*{#1}}%
  \input{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\addnextpagesidebar}[2][]{\afterpage{\addsidebar[#1]{#2}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \color{body}
  \raggedright
}
```

[image]

Comment: please post code as a complete test document that people can use to see the issue and test answers you have posted a fragment using non standard commands and no indication of their definition which makes it very hard to comment.

Comment: latex justifies text, including list items, by default so somewhere in code not shown you seem to have specified `\raggedright` but without seeing the code not much help can be given other than say don't use `\raggedright`.

Comment: I will post the `.cls` of my document in a moment, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Apparently I have deleted `\raggedright` from almost the last line of the edit and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image shows that the text is set `\raggedright` so you should be able to modify the class not to use that, and use the default justified setting.