# Landau notation with optional argument

Tags: expl3, math-operators, latex3, xparse

I would like to create a command for Landau's notations (small o for example), which would have an optional argument consisting of two elements (the variable and the point) separated by a comma. How do I do this?

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% \petito[x, \infty]{\ln x}. Expected result :
$ \underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\mathrm{o}} \left( \ln x \right)$ 

% \petito{\ln x}. Expected result :
$ \mathrm{o} \left( \ln x \right)$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why this is tagged with `expl3`, `latex3` and `xparse`?

Comment: I thought a simple solution would be to use `latex3`as here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87407/iterating-through-comma-separated-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the `\petito[x,\infty]{...}` syntax is bad, both to read and to parse, easier to just use `[x\to\infty]` directly

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\ooo}{o}
\NewDocumentCommand\petito{o m}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
    % normal case
    \ooo\left(#2\right)
  }{
    \ooo_{#1}\left(#2\right)
  }
}
\begin{document}

$\petito[x\to\infty]{\ln x}$

\[
  \petito[x\to\infty]{\ln x}
\]

$ \underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\mathrm{o}} \left( \ln x \right)$ 


$\petito{\ln x}$

$ \mathrm{o} \left( \ln x \right)$ 

\end{document}
```

Notes: `$...$` should **never** write below, that disturbs the line spacing, thus `\DeclareMathOperator*` is used to make a macro that behaves like `\lim`.

Additionally, I'm not a fan of the fence autoscaling, but I've left it here.

Comment: Thank you. Even if it's bad, would it be possible to have a solution with the comma?

Comment: @jowe_19 sure, but I don't have the time to provide it. It should be easy enough to add via some `expl3` macros.

Comment: This can be accomplished using the `>{\SplitArgument{...}{...}}` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the proposed syntax would be clearer or easier than

```
\petito_{x\to\infty}(\log x)
```

or, if you want to specify in an easier way the size of the parentheses,

```
\petito_{x\to\infty}{\log x}
```

with maybe

```
\petito_{x\to\infty}[big]{\log x}
```

for larger parentheses or

```
\petito_{x\to\infty}[*]{\log x}
```

for autosizing ones.

You can realize the latter syntax quite easily with `ltcmd` (formerly `xparse`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\petito}{e{_}O{}m}{%
  \genericlandau{o}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\grando}{e{_}O{}m}{%
  \genericlandau{\mathit{O}}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericlandau}{mmmm}
 {
  \operatorname*{#1}
  \IfValueT{#2}{\sb{#2}}% the subscript
  \jowe_landau_arg:nn { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jowe_landau_arg:nn
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {*}{\left}
    {}{}
   }
   { \use:c { #1l } } (
  #2
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {*}{\right}
    {}{}
   }
   { \use:c { #1r } } )
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\petito{\log x} \\
\petito[big]{\log x} \\
\petito[Big]{\log x} \\
\petito[*]{\frac{\sin x}{x}} \\
\petito_{x\to\infty}{\log x} \\
\petito_{x\to\infty}[big]{\log x} \\
\petito_{x\to\infty}[Big]{\log x} \\
\petito_{x\to\infty}[*]{\frac{\sin x}{x}} \\
\grando{\log x} \\
\grando[big]{\log x} \\
\grando[Big]{\log x} \\
\grando[*]{\frac{\sin x}{x}} \\
\grando_{x\to\infty}{\log x} \\
\grando_{x\to\infty}[big]{\log x} \\
\grando_{x\to\infty}[Big]{\log x} \\
\grando_{x\to\infty}[*]{\frac{\sin x}{x}}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to use `\mleft...\mright` from the `mleftright` package or an equivalent construction.