# Iterate comma separated argument for \author

Tags: comma-separated-list

How to define a macro that accepts comma separated arguments, iterates over the arguments and inserts some command or text between the arguments?

E.g. by checking if the current argument is not the first.

I would like to pass `\mycommand{a,b,c}` and get `a \and b \and c`.

Here is my example using `\author` and `\and`

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ekvcHash\myauthor{author=,affiliation=,email=,}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ c }
    \ekvcValue{author}{#1}\\
    \ekvcValue{affiliation}{#1}
  \end{tabular}
}

% this macro should have comma separated arguments instead of three fixed arguments
\newcommand*{\myauthorslist}[3]{%
  \author{
    \myauthor{#1} \and \myauthor{#2} \and \myauthor{#3} % this should be done by iterating the arguments
  }
}

\begin{document}

\myauthorslist
  {author={Author1},affiliation={University of City1}}
  {author={Author2},affiliation={University of City2}}
  {author={Author3},affiliation={University of City3}}

\title{mytitle}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I.e. pass the arguments like the following:

```latex
\myauthorslist{
  {author={Author1},affiliation={University of City1}}
  ,{author={Author2},affiliation={University of City2}}
  ,{author={Author3},affiliation={University of City3}}
  % ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** What I've tried so far:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ekvcHash\myauthor{long author=,long affiliation=}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ c }
    \ekvcValue{author}{#1}\\
    \ekvcValue{affiliation}{#1}
  \end{tabular}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \myauthorslist { O{ \and } m } {
  \clist_use:nn { #2 } { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\author{
  \myauthorslist{
    \myauthor{author={Author1},affiliation={University of City1}},
    ,\myauthor{author={Author2},affiliation={University of City2}}
    ,\myauthor{author={Author3},affiliation={University of City3}}
  }
}

\title{mytitle}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The previous is working. But I'd like to non repeat `\myauthor` and call it like the following:

```latex
\author{
  \myauthorslist{
    {author={Author1},affiliation={University of City1}},
    ,{author={Author2},affiliation={University of City2}}
    ,{author={Author3},affiliation={University of City3}}
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to use `\myauthor` in `\myauthorslist`. The following is not working:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \myauthorslist { O{ \and } m } {
  \clist_use:nn { #2 } { \myauthor{ #1 } } % <- this is not working!
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired syntax is. Do you want this to work as `\myauthorslist{{cs list},{cs list},...}`?

Comment: \@campa yes. I've updated my question

Comment: In `expl3`, you can use `clists`. Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576767/278534

Comment: \@DavidCarlisle: Sorry. I'm not acquainted with those. Would you mind to provide or refer to an example.

Comment: \@User23456234: Yes. Using `{ O{ \and } m }`. But I don't know how to pass `\myauthor` to `\clist_use:nn { #2 } { #1 }`. I've tried `\clist_use:nn { #2 } { \myauthor{#1} }` but it doesn't work.

Comment: actually you want a clist for the first list then handle each item as keyval (I'd probably have used separate commands rather than the tricky syntax with nested  commas having to be hidden by brace groups)`\author {author={Author1},affiliation={University of City1}}  \author{author={Author2},affiliation={University of City2}} \author{author={Author3},affiliation={University of City3}}`

Comment: \@DavidCarlisle: I've updated my question with what I've tried so far

Comment: Another possibility, without using `expl3`, could be `listofitems` package.

Comment: I would recommend using `\seq_set_from_clist` to fill a sequence from a command which takes a `clist` as argument. Then you can process the sequence with `\seq_use:Nnnn` and specify the separators (nnn). First the separator between exact two items, second the separator between multiple items, third the separator only between the last two of multiple items.

Comment: @lukeflo Why not `\clist_use:Nnnn`?

Comment: \@cfr: AFAIU one advantage of using `seq` is that it can be indexed when mapping to a function via `seq_map_indexed_function`. This is very useful if you want to test whether you are on the first item or elsewhere in the sequence.

Comment: @cfr I'm not sure but if I remember correctly the docs state that seq are faster to process than clists. The mapping could also be interesting for the OP if he wants to use related list entries.

Comment: @lukeflo That's true. There are certainly reasons to turn clists into sequences. But if somebody is just starting out with `expl3` (as seems to be the case here) and the job can be done directly with a `clist`, the direct approach is probably the more straightforward one. Unless the OP needs to do this over and over, the speed difference is likely to be negligible.

Comment: Latex beginners can probably be classified in two groups: those who have a background in other language(s) and those who not. Most of experienced programmers would expect some features of lists which AFAIK are not available in clist: e.g. indexed and pairwise mapping or filtering. BTW: those could be implemented for clist too.

Comment: BTW: Following three quotes from the documentation: "Sequences (defined in l3seq) are safer, faster, and provide more features, so they should often be preferred to comma lists", "Almost all operations on comma lists are noticeably slower than those on sequences so converting the data to sequences using \seq_set_from_clist:Nn (see l3seq) may be advisable if speed is important.", and "The sequence data type should thus certainly be preferred to comma lists to store such items." (see https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#page=182)