# Is there a way to step through two lists of arguments pairwise?

Tags: xparse, arguments

Is there a way to write a macro that steps through two lists of arguments pairwise, like what Python's `zip` function does? For example, I'd like to write a macro like this (using `xparse` because that's what I've been experimenting with; I'm open to other options):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Zip}{ >{\SplitList{,}}m >{\SplitList{,}}m }{%
    % something that calls \myfunc in an itemize environment
}

\newcommand{\myfunc}[2]{\item #1, #2}
```

So that calling `Zip{zebra,frog,jay}{mammal,amphibian,bird}` is equivalent to

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item zebra, mammal
    \item frog, amphibian
    \item jay, bird
\end{itemize}
```

Is this possible? I've looked into `xparse` but it seems to only allow stepping through two lists one at a time, not zipping them together. There was a similar question here [back in 2011](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12187/iterating-through-two-lists), but I hope there's a nicer solution now.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554381/4427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\seq_mapthread_function:NNN` to iterate over two `seq` variables like that.

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__gil_tmpa_seq
\seq_new:N \l__gil_tmpb_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \Zip { m m }
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__gil_tmpa_seq {#1}
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__gil_tmpb_seq {#2}
    \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
      \l__gil_tmpa_seq \l__gil_tmpb_seq \myfunc
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myfunc}[2]{\item #1, #2}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \Zip{zebra,frog,jay}{mammal,amphibian,bird}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, exactly what I need! I'll see if someone has a higher-level solution (I was kind of expecting there to be one) but if not, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @gil How higher-level do you mean? `\seq_mapthread_function:NNN` is a documented interface in `expl3`, so it is really not “low level”.  If you mean something built into `xparse`, then the answer is no, it doesn't have that.

Comment: I mean if some package offers an easy, `xparse`-like interface for zipping (which `xparse` doesn't do, I know), I'd prefer that. Maybe I was hoping for too much.

Comment: @gil It's rather specific, so I don't think so (but there are thousands of packages out there, so there might as well be, but none that I know of).  There's `\foreach` from the `pgffor` package, which is quite powerful and maybe has something to do this (I know it can do a for loop with two counters, like C's `for`; I don't know about arbitrary lists).

Comment: This is essentially identical to my answer to the question marked as duplicate, although not as powerful.

Comment: How could I make this work in case I put the two lists in a command first? So e.g. having `\newcommand{\listone}{zebra,frog,jay}` and `\newcommand{\listtwo}{mammal,amphibian,bird}`, then calling `\Zip{\listone}{\listtwo}`?

Comment: @Steven Replace the two `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn` with `\seq_set_from_clist:NN` (`:NN` instead of `:Nn`)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks for the quick reply, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Using `\foreach` from `pgffor`, to illustrate as per the comment.

Traverse the diagonal of the matrix of pairwise combinations:

```
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {#1}{%
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {#2}{%
\ifnum \xi=\yi%
\item \x , \y 
\fi
}
}
```

[image: zipped pairs]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__gil_tmpa_seq
\seq_new:N \l__gil_tmpb_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \Zip { m m }
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__gil_tmpa_seq {#1}
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__gil_tmpb_seq {#2}
    \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
      \l__gil_tmpa_seq \l__gil_tmpb_seq \myfunc
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myfunc}[2]{\item #1, #2}

\newcommand{\myfuncb}[2]{%
\begin{itemize}
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {#1}{%
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {#2}{%
\ifnum \xi=\yi%
\item \x , \y 
\fi
}
}
\end{itemize}
}



\begin{document}

Expl3:
\begin{itemize}
  \Zip{zebra,frog,jay}{mammal,amphibian,bird}
\end{itemize}

\textbackslash foreach:
\myfuncb{zebra,frog,jay}{mammal,amphibian,bird}

\end{document}
```